# How to get the progress status from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have one Stored Procedure, which more than 100K records in different tables. It's taking 4-5minutes to complete the task. till 4-5mins user dont know what happening in application. Please help me how I can show the progress of Stored Procedure. How can I get the progress status from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

along with the comment posted by Steve, try using [Back Ground Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58.aspx) class and report progress and make UI more responsive.